# Looking for a JS Map control with a callback

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was wondering if anyone knows of a good Javascript/Query map control that will allow the user to click on a position. Once this is done the control would callback with the GPS coordinates that the user just selcted.

Does anyone know of such a control.

I have been looking about but haven't found anything yet.

This is to use in a MVC3 application.

All suggestions welcome.

Comment: I've been looking at this but can't work out how to get a callback when the user selects a point. Do you know if thats possible?

Comment: What have you been looking at?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the Google Maps API (https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/events#EventListeners)

```
var map;
function initialize() 
{
    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-25.363882,131.044922);
    var mapOptions = 
    {
        zoom: 4,
        center: myLatlng,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);

    google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event) 
    {
        placeMarker(event.latLng);
    });
}

function placeMarker(location) 
{
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker(
    {
        position: location,
        map: map
    });

    map.setCenter(location);
}
```

Demo https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/event-arguments

Comment: Great, perfect. I wasn't looking hard enough sorry.